# Subspace scrolling in QT

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar

I have a scrollbar which helps me get to a particular position in a video. Now what I want to do is be able to create a sub-space in that scrollbar area such that once that subspace is decided, the main scrollbar pointer can only run between that subspace. I am using QT for this application.

E.g., If the video is from 0-1000. I need two more pointers on the scrollbar which can be put on 100 and 200. Now once that is done, the video between 100 and 200 is what can be played and the main scrollbar pointer cannot move beyond these boundaries.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is it really a scrollbar, or rather a slider? However, both inherit from QAbstractSlider, which allows you to adapt the range via setMinimum()/setMaximum()/setRange(). Not sure I totally understand the intended behavior though.

Comment: The intent of the behavior is to ultimately train sub-sequence of video for training for tracking and event-detection algorithms. We need to make sure our starting and ending sliders are in the right place for it and hence dynamic change in those position becomes important

Answer (score 0):

The first good thing to do would be to `connect` slot to `valueChanged(int)` of `QAbstractSlider` signal and then in this function (slot) - first adjust slider position to make it in desired range and then update your video surface. Then all that's left is to trigger video stopping on the upper limit of the designated range, that depends on how you implement video playing but probably not that hard.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of it. The main reason for doing this is to be able to train a particular sub-sequence of video for tracking and event detection. Since these two problems are pretty difficult to see whether they will work or not in selected piece, we need to be able to have three different pointers working which will make customers a lot happier. Otherwise this method works great for internal product, not so much when people using it don't want to deal with intricacies.

Comment: @navderm so you meant it like visual pointers? Oh sorry I didn't get the question at first. But I guess I leave this answer for people who confused like me. My first wild guess for solving problem would be to implement two more sliders but override their paint function to draw only slider control (pointer) on the original slider. Their needs to be his children widgets for that I guess, hopefully mouse control functions will not break. (Totally not sure it will work though)

Comment: Ok. I did not know you could draw only slider Control. This does seem contrived but if I can get this working fast enough (half a day) then will try to do so . Thanks ! 
Do you have any example which does the same. Or even a pseudocode in QT form would work great for starting out.

Comment: @navderm Well you can try to implement it similar to `QSlider`s `paintEvent` but with `opt.subControls` set to `QStyle::SC_SliderHandle` only, hopefully it would help) Placing sliders on each other exactly in position maybe won't be that easy though.